# How can we get fresh project after solving all issues on sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube-web

I scanned my project and uploaded to sonarqube. Now, it is giving some issues (bugs, smells, vulnerability, etc). After fixing all the issues, how can we get fresh (or issues solved) project?

Comment: Do you mean what happens once you clean-up all the reported issues?

Comment: Delete existing project and re-upload it again?

Comment: Okay Peska, i got your point.

Comment: Yeah saurabh14292, After clean-up all the issues overview will look like no any issues.